# How to ignore Enter key from WPF modal dialog, in PreviewKeyUp

Tags: .net, wpf, dialog, keyboard, modal-dialog

I have a WPF application. On it's main window it has a PreviewKeyUp handler, to handle certain global key presses - in this case, Enter. 
I've found when a modal dialog is showing (ShowDialog) and enter key is pressed, the enter goes to the PreviewKeyUp handler on the main window.
Depending on your perspective, this may or may not make sense ... but it's definitely not what I want here.

So I can't see any way to intercept the Enter key reliably on the main window (regardless of focussed control), without also being called when Enter is pressed in a modal dialog.

This seems to be behaviour specific to the Enter key - it doesn't happen for other keys, such as digits.

Anyone got any ideas?

**Main window code:**

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Key)
  {
    case Key.Enter:
      Controller.ProductSelected();
      ActionComplete();
      e.Handled = true;
      break;
  }
}


public bool PromptForPassword(string promptText, out string result)
{
  DataEntryForm entryForm = new DataEntryForm();
  entryForm.Owner = this;
  entryForm.PromptText = promptText;

  IsEnabled = false; // doesn't help
  entryForm.ShowDialog();
  IsEnabled = true;

  result = entryForm.EntryData;

  return (bool) entryForm.DialogResult;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting IsEnabled = false on the main window prior to showing the dialog?

Comment: Just tried it - doesn't stop the PreviewKeyUp firing. It appears the window has been re-enabled by the time PreviewKeyUp fires. Also would be a bit ugly since I have to remember to do that around every ShowDialog.

Comment: When you just tried it now, did you use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke?  I checked on mine and the PKU event is swallowed.

Comment: I'm not using any Invoke or BeginInvoke (or background threads in general)...

Comment: I've added code snippets in case I'm doing something different ...

Comment: I did this if it's of any use to you...   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate { IsEnabled = false; }, new object[] { null });  var dr = MessageBox.Show("Hello");              Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate { IsEnabled = true; }, new object[] { null });  and the ENTER key is gone

Comment: Garry, that works! (I found it didn't need the DispatcherPriority.Input). If you put it as a solution I will accept it. But I don't understand why it is necessary to set the IsEnabled in a BeginInvoke. Aren't we all on the UI thread here?

Comment: I added the answer.  You'll need the dispatcher if the dialog is doing any sort of heavy lifting when it loads.  I recommend keeping it :)

Comment: Well, it's not just a recommendation - this doesn't work without the Dispatcher! And I don't understand why. But maybe this isn't the place for it.

Comment: The 'why' is that the dispatcher initiates a thread on the UI that is not BLOCKED by the invocation of MessageBox.  And the IsEnabled=false tells the window not receive focus.  So the keystroke is sent to the MessageBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that situation I did this if it's of any use to you...

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, 
            (SendOrPostCallback)delegate { IsEnabled = false; }, new object[] { null }); 
var dr = MessageBox.Show("Hello"); 
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, 
            (SendOrPostCallback)delegate { IsEnabled = true; }, new object[] { null });
```

and the ENTER will be swallowed by the dialog box.

Comment: Thanks Garry. As noted before, I don't understand why the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is required, but this does work, and it doesn't work without the BeginInvoke.

Comment: I've since found that this solution isn't that practical. I need to get the focus back to the form, and that causes the Enter key to be processed again. See my other solution...

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler and Inclusive solution for this problem is to catch the key press event and not to let it proceed down to the dialog behind the top dialog:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        // whatever your code should do when the event fires...

        // swallow Enter key so it won't
        // press buttons under the current dialog
        e.Handled = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Garry's solution leaves focus problems.

This problem seems to only occur when using **IsDefault** on the OK button in the dialog. Therefore a simple solution without side effects is to instead handle the enter key in a PreviewKeyUp event.

```
public partial class MyDialog : Window
{
    ...

    private void Window_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Key)                
        {
            case Key.Enter:
                OKButton_Click(sender,e);
                break;
        }

    }
```

This is perhaps a generalised problem with access keys, since the Enter key press is supposedly handled by just registering an access key. Perhaps it's this access key scoping issue:
http://coderelief.net/2012/07/29/wpf-access-keys-scoping/

The downside is you have to change all dialog windows to work this way - a little ugly, but it's not a lot of code.